# Error '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list C++

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguente código:

```
struct Estado {
    string nombre;
    int costo; // costo para alcanzar este estado
    bool visitado;
    vector<pair<int, Estado>> vecinos; // vecinos del estado (costo para alcanzarlos, estado)
    
    // Constructor
    Estado(string nombre = "", int costo = 0, bool visitado = false) : nombre(nombre), costo(costo), visitado(visitado) {}
};
```

Al ejecutar en el compilador me sale el siguiente error:

> *Error] '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list*

¿Cómo podría arreglarlo o que puedo hacer?, uso `dev-C++` `5.11`.

Comment: ¿Dónde dices que ocurre el error? No veo ninguno https://tio.run/##bVDBbsMgDL3zFVZ7IVLW7rxkuUz7EJd4FRLBEZAeVuXbMweoqkrjYOwH79l@Zp7frsZs29F645aRoLccUyCcBvXEbmQSh0GpJVp/BY8TxRkNQUxjp5QQFpPgOyYcGe4K5AiWv/J0CdRlyPoERtS5g/O5ZDBjQEBn0P9iAIqJ9iAymXFhdnCz0e5IESmj9DPa0ItgW7sOw/5iPccsXnMYyVU90P80dBzb@t5k9RyE/8W@LMUhQ6WJflkKPuFwaJ9bSf3evo4s0A@6SA18VJIuV9MWThlKqgdDP5IG7qtaxdxdf0LrdVOdrTZXUw0vCfoe6FSsVeu2/QE

Comment: Puede que se deba a un error de tu propio compilador al manejar plantillas. Para asegurarte de que tu compilador entienda el código inserta un espacio entre `>>` en la línea `vector<pair<int, Estado> > vecinos;`. Esto se hace para indicar al compilador que estos no forman parte de una lista de plantillas anidada. Te recomiendo también trabajar con una versión de `Dev-C++` más reciente, ya que puede que algunos compiladores tengas problemas con la expresión `>>` que mencionas.

Comment: @Londo no es un error de compilador: es un comportamiento estandarizado del mismo. Esa estandarización cambió a partir de C++11 .

Answer (score 2):

Tu compilador está confundiendo el "*doble mayor qué*" (`>>`) correspondiente a dos cierres de [paréntesis angulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A9ntesis):

> ###### Wikipedia
>
> Los paréntesis angulares son diferentes de los símbolos matemáticos de desigualdad: los primeros son de ángulo obtuso y los segundos, de ángulo agudo.

Con el operador de desplazamiento de bits a la derecha (`>>`). Este es un error conocido que fue solucionado en el estándar C++11. [Aquí](https://wg21.link/N1757) puedes consultar el documento técnico que menciona la corrección de ese problema.

Para solucionarlo, deberás configurar tu compilador para que use un estándar de C++ igual o superior a C++11.